search within rows and columns based on two search criteria and select a single cell vba

The image below is for illustration purposes only.



I am using this VBA code, But it support only Single search criteria.

Is there any way to apply both search criteria to select related cell?
Because both search criteria can change every time.
Sub Find_Items()
Dim rFound As Range

  Set rFound = ActiveSheet.Columns(2).Find(What:=ActiveSheet.Range("L3").Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
  
  If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
  
   rFound.Offset(0, 3).Select
End If
End Sub


Using WorksheetFunction functions this is the code:
Sub twocrit()
Set res = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
Set res = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("C3:G12"), WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("L3"), Range("B3:B12"), 0), WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("L4"), Range("C2:G2"), 0))
On Error GoTo 0
If res Is Nothing Then MsgBox ("Not valid input!"): Exit Sub
res.Select
Range("L7") = res.Address
End Sub



Try this one.
It works for me.
Sub FindCell()

    Dim WS As Worksheet, tmp As Range
    Dim SearchItem As String, SearchGrade As String
    Dim FoundRow As Range, FoundColumn As Range
    Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    SearchItem = WS.Range("L3").Value
    SearchGrade = WS.Range("L4").Value
    If SearchItem = "" Or SearchGrade = "" Then _
    MsgBox "Please enter search criteria!", vbExclamation, "Error": Exit Sub
    On Error Resume Next
    Set FoundRow = WS.Columns("B").Find(What:=SearchItem, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    On Error GoTo 0
    On Error Resume Next
    Set FoundColumn = WS.Rows(2).Find(What:=SearchGrade, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not FoundRow Is Nothing And Not FoundColumn Is Nothing Then
        Set tmp = WS.Cells(FoundRow.Row, FoundColumn.Column)
        tmp.Select
        Range("L7") = tmp.Address
    Else
  MsgBox "No matching cell found for the given criteria!", vbExclamation, "Error"
 End If
End Sub

Hope it helps!

Your code is close to finish. Add a Find clause to search keyword in row 2.
Sub Demo()
    Dim gradeC As Range, itemC As Range, c As Range
    Set gradeC = Rows(2).Find(what:=Range("L4"), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    Set itemC = Columns(2).Find(what:=Range("L3"), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If gradeC Is Nothing Or itemC Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Can't find the target cell."
    Else
        Set c = Cells(itemC.Row, gradeC.Column)
        Range("L7") = c.Address(0, 0)
        c.Select
        ' other code
    End If
End Sub



I don't know, why this code is not working. Nothing Happening.

The code was tesed with the sample data which is showed on your screenshot.

I have got three answers against my Question. Two answers are working good but not this one. Sorry, I don't know why? Can't find the target cell.

I've fixed the typo. Pls try again. Btw, On Error Resume Next is not needed in the script.

Thanks Mr. @taller, The answer you gave is the best one as per the question I asked, but I have already accepted someone else's answer.

Thank you for your kind words! While marking an answer as accepted can indeed guide others to the solution more quickly, I completely understand and respect your decision.
You have the right to change it if you wish.
